# Android Kotlin Pass ArrayList<> To 2nd Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList` from my `MainActivity` to my `MeasuringActivity`. I have come across an issue that I'm not sure how to get around. I am using an SDK and the class I am using for the ArrayList doesn't implement Serialization or Parcelable, the class is readonly as well so I can't edit it.

Here is my `ArrayList` code `private val mDeviceList: ArrayList<XsensDotDevice> = ArrayList()`, due to the `XsensDotDevice` class not implementing Serilization or Parcelable im not sure how to pass the ArrayList to my MeasuringActivity via `Intent`.

Here is the code I wrote to pass the variable

```
val intent = Intent(this, MeasuringActivity::class.java)
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putSerializable("product", mDeviceList)
intent.putExtras(bundle)
startActivity(intent)
```

I then receive the following error when it tries to pass the variable

```
2020-07-24 23:36:42.083 28178-28178/com.example.bodymotion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bodymotion, PID: 28178
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.xsens.dot.android.sdk.models.XsensDotDevice@3a003ac
```

Is there another way of passing this variable over to the other activity which I may not have come across? I am new to android development so sorry if some of this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have You tried using GSON and data classes? You can convert an array of any data class to JSON string and then just pass it as a string and convert JSON to an array

Comment: @iknow, yet I would suggest the same.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add below dependency in module level Gradle file.:**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

**2. Send list object as below:**

```
    val list = ArrayList<SomeJavaClass>()

    val stringData = Gson().toJson(list)

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("DATA_PASS", stringData)
    startActivity(intent)
```

**3. Receive list object in 2nd Activity as:**

```
     intent.hasExtra("DATA_PASS").let {

        if (it) {

            val listType: Type =
                object : TypeToken<List<SomeJavaClass>>() {}.type
            val listRcvd = Gson().fromJson(
                intent.getStringExtra("DATA_PASS"),
                listType
            ) as List<SomeJavaClass>

            println(listRcvd)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi sorry I have only just had chance to look at this, thank you for providing your example. I am now receiving the following error `class com.example.bodymotion.MainActivity declares multiple JSON fields named mLifecycleRegistry`

Comment: Could you please share your code especially the class you wanted to pass in intent?